# How can I replace only a certain percentage of a region?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-worldedit

In WorldEdit, you can do something like `//replace stone 20%air,80%stone`, but I want the inverse. I want a region that has a lot of block types replace only the 20% of the region with another. This can be done with `//replace %20 air` but I want to concatenate it with #existing tag but `//replace %20#existing air` doesn't work. Is there any solution with masks or something?

A solution will be some command that let me replace 1 block of the selection with air that isn't air.